Perform comparisons across a set of rows
I have a problem with a query in snowflake that I cannot currently solve with the help of SQL.
I have a table with 5 columns (nr, name, startdate, calc_date, bygr), which is structured as follows:

Now I need to find out, if the person in column name has a change in column bygr. But I do need only those people, where a change in the bygr exist and the calc_date changed (the yellow marked rows).
The BYGR is a value which I concatenated over 4 columns (bygr_av, bygr_rv, bygr_kv, bygr_pv).
I tried it with a cte like this, but it doesn't really work (it shows not the diffs):
with base_cte as (
    select 
        nr,
        concat(name, ', ', firstname) as name,
        date_start,
        calc_date,
        concat(
            bygr_av,
            bygr_kv,
            bygr_pv,
            bygr_rv
        ) as BYGR 
    from my_table
    where datediff(month, date_start, date_end) > 1 /* I need contracts with start and enddate in different months */
    group by 
        nr,
        name,
        date_start,
        calc_date,
        BYGR
),
fokus_month as (
    select
        nr,
        name,
        date_start
    from (
        select 
            nr,
            name,
            date_start,
            calc_date
        from base_cte
        group by 
            nr,
            name,
            date_start,
            calc_date
        )    
),
fokus_bygr as (
    select
        nr,
            name,
            date_start,
    from (
        select 
            nr,
            name,
            date_start,
            bygr
        from base_cte
        group by
            nr,
            name,
            date_start,
            bygr 
        )    
)

select 
    nr,
    name,
    date_start
from fokus_bygr
union
select 
    nr,
    name,
    date_start
from fokus_monat
order by nr asc, date_start desc
;

My aim would be, that the sql in snowflake is able to show me the yellow highlighted results from the attached images (for one person having different calc_dates and different bygr but same date_start). Is this possible??
Any help would be very fine :-) Thanks a lot :-)

Please show sample data and expected output. Also, as per the [ask], please do not post images of code, data, error message, etc. Instead, copy or type the text into your question, formatted as code. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

If you help us reproduce the data, we can help you rewrite the query faster
